# Parallel testing with cucumber and Gradle

Tags: java, testing, cucumber

I keep finding posts and articles on how to run parallel tests with Cucumber and Maven, but nothing with Gradle.

I have the following scenario:

```
  Scenario Outline: Author from API matches author on book page
    Given user goes on google.com
    when user search <item>
    and click on <locator>
    Then something happens

    Examples:
      | item    | locator |
      | item1   | locator1|
      | item2   | locator2|
      | item3   | locator3|
```

Is it possible, with Gradle, to run this scenario in parallel, each execution using the values in "Examples" table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible! But you have to apply some workarounds.

```kotlin
plugins {
    java
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.2"))
    testImplementation(platform("io.cucumber:cucumber-bom:7.11.1"))

    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-java")
    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine")
    testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    // Work around. Gradle does not include enough information to disambiguate
    // between different examples and scenarios.
    systemProperty("cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy", "long")
}
```

Because Gradle provides rather limited support for tests that aren't a in class file you have to use the `junit-platform-suite` to declare a suite.

```java
package io.cucumber.skeleton;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("io/cucumber/skeleton")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "io.cucumber.skeleton")
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

This suite will target the `cucumber` TestEngine from [`cucumber-junit-platform-engine`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#cucumber-junit-platform-engine). The [cucumber-java-skeleton](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/tree/main/gradle) contains a working (serial) example.

To make the tests execute in parallel you can add to `junit-platform.properties`:

```
cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=true
```

That is it. For more config details check the JUnit 5 and Cucumber JUnit Platform Engine documentation.

Comment: I understand that the first snippet is from build.gradle
The second is the class used to run your cucumber test
What about the "cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=true" ? Where should I put it ?

Comment: In the `junit-platform.properties` file. The file goes under `src/test/resources`. You can check the working example if you have more questions like this.